# Change #define argument

Tags: ios, preprocessor

I'd wrote a preprocessor define statement for a getter method

```c
#define GetNSStringDefaultForPropertyWithNameAndKey(propertyName, propertyKey) - (NSString *)propertyName { return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:_userDefaultsKey][propertyKey];  }
```

but got stuck when doing the same for the setter method as I'd have to modify propertyName argument to setPropertyName.

Is there way to do this kind of argument modification.

EDIT
I should have said that both definitions should overwrite the compiler generated getter/setter methods.
But if I got Matthias right, the only way is to provide a capitalized version of the property in question like so.

```
#define SetNSStringDefaultForPropertyWithNameAndKey(PropertyName, propertyKey) - (void)set  ## PropertyName:(NSString *)newValue \  
{ \  
    self.userDefaults[propertyKey] = newValue; \
    [self updateUserDefaults]; \
} \
```

Comment: If you edit the code in the question please do it in a way that actually works. You can't put #defines on multiple lines like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `##` to concatenate two tokens together. However the preprocessor can't change the case of a token. So you have to provide a uppercase property name yourself.

Something like this should work

```c
#define SetNSStringDefaultForPropertyWithNameAndKey(propertyName, propertyKey) - (void)set ## propertyName:(id)object { [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: _userDefaultsKey][propertyKey] = object; }
```

And because the preprocessor can't change to uppercase you have to provide the property name with the first letter capitalized

```
SetNSStringDefaultForPropertyWithNameAndKey(Foobar, @"foobar")

GetNSStringDefaultForPropertyWithNameAndKey(foobar, @"foobar")
```

Comment: Just made my defines with a precondition so that propertyNameKey must be the first-character capitalized version of propertyName so that I have both available. Thanks.